# How to disable iTerm2 tmux integration

Tags: tmux, macos, iterm2

iTerm2 runs slowly when using `tmux` (without `-CC` control mode integration). It is clearly designed with the intention of using `-CC`.

However, I don't like the desktop window management of tmux windows/panes. I want tmux keyboard shortcuts and everything in a single iTerm2 window.

Is there a way to disable tmux integration in iTerm2 so that I can `tmux` without using `-CC`? And so that it won't lag?

If you are having difficulty trying to reproduce, try opening 2 tabs attached to the same tmux session. Compare it's I/O performance to the system terminal attached to the same tmux session.

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution but a workaround - I discovered the incredible wezterm which is all I need. Here is my config.

```
hugh@Hughs-Mac-mini ~ % cat ~/.wezterm.lua
local wezterm = require 'wezterm';

wezterm.on("toggle-alert", function(window, pane)
        local overrides = window:get_config_overrides() or {}
        if not overrides.color_scheme then
                overrides.color_scheme = "Red Alert"
        else
                overrides.color_scheme = nil
        end
        window:set_config_overrides(overrides)
end)

return {
  font = wezterm.font("IBM Plex Mono", {weight="Regular"}),
  font_size = 15,
  freetype_load_target = "Light",
  color_scheme = "AdventureTime",
  enable_tab_bar = false,
  default_cursor_style = "BlinkingBlock",
  keys = {
    {key="A", mods="CTRL", action=wezterm.action{EmitEvent="toggle-alert"}},
  },
}
```